# error while php imap_fetchheader "invalid mailbox list: <>"

Tags: php, error-handling, imap

I'm running the command imap_fetchheader and get the error message "invalid mailbox list: <>". I guess it's because of bad email header. There is a line in the header like that: "Cc: <>".

That's the part of my code the error occures:

```
        $neu_header = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $email_number, FT_UID);
    
        if(imap_last_error()) {
            error_log('Error while imap_fetchheader: ' . imap_last_error());
            imap_errors();
            }

        // delete "<>" from header
        $count = 0;
        $neu_header = str_replace("<>","",$neu_header,$count);
            if ($count <> 0) error_log($count . " Mal <> ersetzt");

        // parse headers
        $neu_header_array = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($neu_header);
        if(imap_last_error()) {
            error_log('Error while imap_rfc822_parse_headers: ' . imap_last_error());
            imap_errors();
            }
                
        $neu_to = $neu_header_array->to;
```

The error is not causing any further problems if I delete the "<>" before parsing the header. But I don't like not delaing with an error proberly. Any suggestions how to solve that issue?

Thanks a lot,
Markus

Comment: `Cc: <>` is simply not valid, it should contain an email address between those brackets. So if you are getting already "broken" input data, then you don't have much of a choice, other than trying to fix the problem this way. Or - let it run into the error, and then reject this particular email completely.

Comment: reject is no solution... ist there any dokumentation on the errorhandling of that imap function. In my case there is a error message but still a return. I'm wondering if there could be a case where there is no return.